# How do I change the background color for a column of my Android app

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

My Android app has a table with seven columns.  I'd like to change the background color of these columns when the content in the table is updated.  How do I specify columns in the main.xml and how do I change their background color?  Thanks.

Edit main.xml posted...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CDCDCD" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="1"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="2"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="4"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="5"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="6"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="7"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="1"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="2"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView14" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="4"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView15" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="5"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView16" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="6"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView17" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="7"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

This is an example of why I want to highlight the entire column instead of the individual textviews.  When I highlight the individual textviews they are different sizes so they do not expand to the width of the widest textview in that column.  Unless anyone knows how to change the size of my text views to fit the size of the widest textview in each column.  If anyone does know this, please post.

[image: uneven highlighting]

EDIT:
Results of adding layout_weight properties to the TableRow tag...

[image]

I also tried the same thing but added the layout_weight property to the TextView tag instead.  Here is the result...

[image]

Comment: Show us your XML layout so far

Comment: Was just thinking.  Would it be possible to declare a layout as a horizontal layout and that way the table would be organized by column and not by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give your textviews equal width and therefore fix your higlighting issue you should look at the layout_weight property

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#CDCDCD" 
     android:orientation="vertical">
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="1"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow   
       android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
       android:layout_width="0dip" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView android:text="100" android:id="@+id/textView11" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="1"></TextView>            
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I'm not at my development PC so can't verify this (and fix my formatting), but it should work I'll check it later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was aware of the layout_width property.  However, I was never able to make it work properly.  I tried your solution posted above but it did not work.  I also tried adding the layout_weight property to the TextView instead of the TableRow, but that also didn't work.  I still get the same uneven highlighting.  I will post a picture in my original post.

Comment: @bitnuk3r it looks like layout_weight is working you just then need to add layout_gravity="center" to the layout above. Sorry I havent got my dev computer with me to double check

Comment: At first your solution was not working for me.  Then I decided to start from scratch.  I created a new android project and recreated my tables.  I centered the TextViews like you said and now the highlighting is even.  I pasted my fixed table from the new android project into the old project and all the highlighting looks even now.  I'm not sure why this worked but it did. I think I should have tried going to Project->Clean in the Eclipse menu but eveything is working now.  Also, I did use layout_weight but I found that I didn't need it, the highlighting was still even.  Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest solution but you could change the background color of all the TextViews in the column.

```
TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textview11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
textview2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
textview11.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I had though of that solution but it gets complicated as I add more columns and textviews to the table.  Also I cannot get my textviews to expand to the width of the widest textview in each column.  This maked the highlighting look uneven (see pic I posted above).  I need to be able to have even highlighting on each column.  I think the best way to do this would be to highlight the column, not each individual textview.

Comment: Try the solution Blundell provided in his answer. Or you can also try changing to android:layout_width="fill_parent" on the TextViews, might work but I can not test it right now. And yeah would be better to be able to handle to whole column as a unit. Looked briefly at the documentation but did not find anything...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a series of nested linear layouts, a full-screen horizonal one with evenly spaced vertical ones for the columns.  If I then set the TextView background to transparent, I can change the entire column background by setting the background of the column's LinearLayout.