# Change programmatically background color the entire column in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

Is it possible, that change programmatically color background the entire column in TableLayout?

Look this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unbDY.jpg

Comment: get a loop for all the column and change the color of each column individually

Comment: Please make sure you have read and understood the API documentation before asking questions. Also a search is very helpful. Such question are already answered a million times.

Comment: Yes guys, but I think about something other, look this: http://imgur.com/FgjaeOJ

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
  TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) findViewById(rowID);
                   tableRow .setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of this way;

---

```
tr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

---

[checkout this stack explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641103/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-for-a-column-of-my-android-app)

Comment: you have to set logic if you are using two TableLayout i.e when to change color but you can change color by above syntax as written in my answer @Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout_sample);
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.table_row);
tableRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light));
```